# Is there any software for routing? I don't want specific route distribution

Tags: networking, server, software-recommendation, router

I'm trying to find some graphic software to **manage a network server**, and for using it **like router**. And I want some general **overview** of what is happening on the network. In Windows, I reached for **Kerio WinRoute**. But is there something similar for Linux? I searched on internet, but I found only some "route distributions" and I don't want now install them.

I use **Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 - 64bit**

Comment: Try asking on [unix.se]. Ask Ubuntu deals only with Ubuntu.

Comment: nginx  and/or  express

Comment: @Zacharee1 I use Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I want this software install here.

Comment: @BlueManCZ your title says "No distribution," which led me to believe you weren't asking about Ubuntu specifically.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Sorry for inaccuracy, but it means: I don't want sepicific "route distribution" like pfsense or zeroshell.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Oh, that makes sense. I'll retract my close vote, but you should probably add a specification. There are a lot of people who ask questions here about Mint, Fedora and even Windows without specifying the OS.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yes, I know these people. For sure and better comprehensibility I edited question. :)